# Android - perform an action in background every few minutes

Tags: java, android

I've written the code to perform some action every 5 minutes, regardless if the application is currently on the foreground or not. I'd like to get a feedback about correctness - have I chosen the right API to do the work and is it implemented correctly?

This is the code:

`PeriodicActionFacade.java` which is the entry point to the feature (its `start` and `stop` methods can be bound to buttons):

```
class PeriodicActionFacade {
    private final Context context;
    private final PeriodicExecutor executor;

    PeriodicActionFacade(final Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.executor = PeriodicExecutor.INSTANCE;
    }

    void start() {
        context.startService(new Intent(context, PeriodicActionService.class));
    }

    void stop() {
        executor.terminate();
    }
}
```

`PeriodicActionService` which is starting the `PeriodicExecutor` as the foreground service:

```
public class PeriodicActionService extends IntentService {

    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private final PeriodicExecutor executor;

    public PeriodicActionService() {
        super(PeriodicActionService.class.getSimpleName());
        executor = PeriodicExecutor.INSTANCE;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable final Intent intent) {
        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, buildNotification());
        executor.executeBlocking();
        stopForeground(true);
        stopSelf();
    }

    private Notification buildNotification() {
        return new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NotificationChannels.PERIODIC_ACTION)
                .setContentTitle("Ongoing periodic action")
                .setContentText("Ongoing periodic action")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                .build();
    }
}
```

`PeriodicExecutor` which is responsible for executing the action every 5 minutes unless `terminate` is called:

```
enum PeriodicExecutor {
    INSTANCE;

    private boolean isRunning;
    private CountDownLatch latch;

    void executeBlocking() {
        isRunning = true;
        while (isRunning) {
            latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
            performAction();
            try {
                latch.await(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            } catch (InterruptedException ignored) { }
        }
    }

    private void performAction() {
        // Here I'm performing the action
        Log.i(PeriodicExecutor.class.getSimpleName(), "I'm performing periodic action!");
    }

    void terminate() {
        isRunning = false;
        latch.countDown();
    }
}
```

Comment: where do you start the service after 5 minutes ? I don't see that code

Comment: @Jabbar_Jigariyo Sorry, during edit, I've changed accidentaly time to 10 seconds ;) I've corrected it and now the waiting is in the line `latch.await(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);`